# Extracting certain part of string encapsulated inside tag

Tags: php, regex

I am working with large strings and want to implement a regex or similar solution to extract a certain part from the string. The part I want to extract is encapsulated by `[test ][/test]` tags inside the string. Everything outside tag would be removed. How could I do this efficiently with PHP?

```
   $subject = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

[test ]https://www.test.com/this_a_test[/test]";

$pattern = '~\[test (?|=[\'"]?+([^]"\']++)[\'"]?+]([^[]++)|](([^[]++)))\[/test]~';
$replacement = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
var_dump( $result );
```

Current output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. https://www.test.com/this_a_test
```

Desired output:

```
https://www.test.com/this_a_test
```

Comment: Have you looked at regex for extracting bbcode? maybe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508013/url-bbcode-regex

Comment: \\[test\\s\\](.*)\\[\/test\\] on MATCH 1.  https://regex101.com/#pcre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the substring inside the markers with the following regex:

```
\[test\s*](.*?)\[\/test]
```

You need to use `preg_match_all` with this regex.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hX6qJ6/1)

And [IDEONE Demo](http://ideone.com/VEcFSM):

```
$re = '~\[test\s*](.*?)\[\/test]~s'; 
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\n\n[test ]https://www.test.com/this_a_test[/test]"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.test.com/this_a_test
)
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting the answer if it proved helpful to you.